# How to implement this to my index.html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to implement this function  http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ and connect this on my Internet store with buying things, so you choose items(on images) and selections save to variable and this variable says to support payment how much user want to pay me. The problem is that I don't know how to do it. I linked js, css from inside but in source code there are files with folders like coffee and sassy. Any ideas? :) I don't have experience with Javascript and jQuery I just want do this feature :).

this is certain file index.html

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<script src="js.js"></script>



<!-- scripts for imagepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/image-picker.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image-picker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ja/image-picker.min.js"></script>

<!--code for imagepicker-->
<select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-html">
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>
</select>

</head>
<body><script>

$("select").imagepicker()

</script>

    <select class="image-picker show-html">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option data-img-src="image-path goes here" value="1">Image 1</option>
      <option data-img-src="image-path goes here" value="2">Image 2</option>

    </select></body>


</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug in console after adding the code I provided? What error do you get, you can see there if any files are missing. Also, is `ja/image-picker.min.js` an error or you have a folder named `ja`

Comment: Remove first `select` from `<head>` !!!

Comment: I see, it's images, anyway after change there is nothing

Comment: Your code is correct, there is your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LLfhvrt/1/). You have a mistake in the direction of the scripts or images.

Comment: Your code is haywire. Follow proper format atleast while posting online. Not sure what are the `hrefs` you've added `js.js` `css.css`

Comment: Thank you guys you are the best! it's working on my page :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, please select an answer, so others can move on.

Comment: Anyone knows how to check if user actually is clicking on image? As I said I want to add this information to variable and then say support payment how much user want to pay me :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once, you have downloaded the files and added to project. Add below on your HTML page:

EDIT: This should work for you, I guess

```
<html>
<head>


        <!-- scripts for imagepicker -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/image-picker.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image-picker.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image-picker.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        $("select").imagepicker();

        </script>
</head>
    <body>
    <!--code for imagepicker-->
        <select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-html">
          <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
          <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
          <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
          <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>
        </select>

            <select class="image-picker show-html">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option data-img-src="image-path goes here" value="1">Image 1</option>
              <option data-img-src="image-path goes here" value="2">Image 2</option>

            </select>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay but what about files? I don't know if I linked it correctly to my index.html. There are image-picker.min.js image-picker.js  image-picker.css and these mystery named image-picker.scss and image-picker.coffee . My all code for linking in my index.html is in my question

Comment: This is not readable, please update entire your code in question

Comment: @oreo3311 If you have files in folder `css/` and `js/`, just add `$("select").imagepicker();` to run the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install CoffeeScript first to use this http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ if you prefer using coffee folder.

On ubuntu machine you can use following command

```
sudo npm install -g coffee-script
```

And than in the script which you had download from here - http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ in that do following:

a. Create folder named "img" and some images with name - 01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg, 04.jpg. Give full permissions.

b. Create one file imagepicker.html. This file should be placed outside directory "image-picker", and copy following code in that file.

c. Run HTML file in browser.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image-picker/image-picker.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="image-picker/image-picker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<div class="picker"> 
<select multiple="multiple" class='image-picker show-html'>
<option data-img-src='img/01.jpg' value='1'>  Page 1  </option>
<option data-img-src='img/02.jpg' value='2'>  Page 2  </option>
<option data-img-src='img/03.jpg' value='3'>  Page 3  </option>
<option data-img-src='img/04.jpg' value='4'>  Page 4  </option>
</select>
</div>

<ul class="thumbnails image_picker_selector" style="display: none">
<li><div class="thumbnail"><img class="image_picker_image" src="img/01.jpg"></div></li>
<li><div class="thumbnail"><img class="image_picker_image" src="img/02.jpg"></div></li>
<li><div class="thumbnail"><img class="image_picker_image" src="img/03.jpg"></div></li>
<li><div class="thumbnail"><img class="image_picker_image" src="img/04.jpg"></div></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery("select.image-picker").imagepicker({
  hide_select:  false,
});

jQuery("select.image-picker.show-labels").imagepicker({
  hide_select:  false,
  show_label:   true,
});

jQuery("select.image-picker.limit_callback").imagepicker({ 
  limit_reached:  function(){alert('We are full!')},
  hide_select:    false
}); 

//Return total amount on click of options in drop down. considering $50 for each item
$('.image-picker').click(function(){ 
   var amount = 0; 
   $('.image-picker option:selected').each(function()
   { 
     amount = amount + 50; 
  }); 
  alert("Final Amount - "+amount);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you dude! I have two more problems. What about integrating this image picker with function that count how much you should pay? For instance if I clicked 1 image, total amount is 50$ in my variable, if clicked 2 images total amount is 100$ and so on? How to do this? And what about choosing location of images?

Comment: Dude.. Added this script for dropdown:     

 $('.image-picker').click(function(){  
     var amount = 0;  
     $('.image-picker option:selected').each(function(){ 
         amount = amount + 50;  
     });      
       alert("Final Amount - "+amount);
    });

Comment: So what should I do to achieve that?

Comment: From my above comment, ADD that jquery script in ur script tags at end.
Please check my code(in answer above) I had edited that. 
On evey click it will return total amount with respect to selected items.

Comment: Any chance to do this image picker responsive?

Comment: Responsive? In what sense? css browser compatibility?

Comment: I made my page with using Bootstrap and after testing image picker I perceived that dimension of it never change. How do you think, is there any possibility to do this responsive for example to look normal on my mobile phone? :)

Comment: Try adding this style. <STYLE>
  .image_picker_image { width:100% !important; height:100% !important; } @ media screen and (min-width:320px){
    ul.thumbnails.image_picker_selector li .thumbnail { width: 60px !important; height: 60px !important;}
  }
  @media screen and (min-width:360px){
    ul.thumbnails.image_picker_selector li .thumbnail { width: 70px !important; height: 70px !important;}
  }  @ media screen and (min-width:360px){
    ul.thumbnails.image_picker_selector li .thumbnail { width: 100px !important; height: 100px !important;}
  } </STYLE> AND adjust width as per your needs :)